# bash: A: unrecognized history modifier

Tags: bash

After running a c program, giving it some input on the command line (the program simulates a pushdown automata), I get the following response:

bash: A: unrecognized history modifier

I have googled, but I can't find an explanation as to what this means exactly. My program works with other test input, so I assume it's something to do with the input rather than my program (lol).

Cheers in advance

Joe

Answer (score 18):

*bash* provides “history expansion” when you use an exclamation point (`!`) on the command line (except inside single quotes, after a backslash, or if history expansion is disabled).

If you have an exclamation point in your command line or here document, you should escape or quote it.

See the *bash* documentation for [History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) and its subsections: [Event Designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators), [Word Designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators), and [Modifiers](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) for all the details.

Answer (score 3):

Please add the exact command line you are using. I guess you have '!' in it, which you did not escape.